# Model doesn't update when pass validation array to update method?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

This method **doesn't work:**

```
public function update(Category $category) {
    $data = request()->validate([
        'name' => 'required',
    ]);

    $category->update([
        $data
    ]);

    return redirect("/category/{$category->id}/edit");
}
```

But it **works fine**, like that:

```
public function update(Category $category) {
    $data = request()->validate([
        'name' => 'required',
    ]);

    $category->update([
        'name' => request()->input('name')
    ]);

    return redirect("/category/{$category->id}/edit");
}
```

Result from `dd($data)` in first case is :

```
array:1 [▼
  "name" => "test"
]
```

I'm using first way in other conrollers and it also works, I'm confused.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you can see in the `dd($data)`, `$data` is already an array with keys named as the validated fields. What you are doing is wrap it again inside another array:

```
$category->update([
    $data
]);
```

So that is equivalent to:

```
$category->update([
    [
        'name' => 'test',
    ],
]);
```

Try it like this instead:

```
$category->update($data);
```